# Getting a base map instead of the one specified through data

Tags: r, r-sf, r-leaflet

I downloaded the shapefile to plot Iowa Counties from here - https://geodata.iowa.gov/dataset/county-boundaries-iowa/resource/183e782f-2d43-4073-8524-fe8e634cf17a

However, when I try plotting a map, I only get the base map and not County-level data.

```
mymap<-st_read("county.shp")
str(mymap)
library(leaflet)
# map the polygons in shp
mymap %>% 
  leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons()
```

In addition, I get the following warnings -

```
Warning messages:
1: sf layer is not long-lat data 
2: sf layer has inconsistent datum (+proj=utm +zone=15 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs).
Need '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84'
```

I am a beginner in this arena and would highly appreciate any assistance on this issue.

Comment: It seems that you need to change your CRS. `mymap <- st_read("county.shp") %>% st_transform(crs = 4326)`. Try this. Then, `leaflet(data = mymap) %>% addTiles() %>% addPolygons()`. I can see polygons in Iowa on my PC screen.

Comment: @jazzurro This is awesome. Could you please tell me why did you change your crs?

Comment: See the warning message. It says all.

Comment: @jazzurro Interesting...
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @jazzurro's comment as the answer for future seekers -

```
mymap<-st_read("county.shp")%>% st_transform(crs = 4326)
str(mymap)
library(leaflet)
# map the polygons in shp
mymap %>% 
  leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons()
```

Apparently, I had forgotten to specify the Coordinate Reference System which led to the issue.